# Fetchを使うと　全てのJS関数が無効になります。

Tags: javascript

testLoad 何に、fetchを書くと何故か、JSの関数が定義されていないと怒られ、挙動がおかしくなります。
どうすれば良いでしょうか。

stacker?id=9:205 Uncaught ReferenceError: formationFunction is not defined
at HTMLInputElement.onclick (stackover?id=9:205)

```
  function testLoad(){
        responceData = {};
        let myFetch = fetch(url);
        
        myFetch.then(response => response.json()).then(
            clearDataElementList();
                responceData =>{
                        var param = "&cost=100";
                        var url = "http://....." + param;
                        createLink(url)
                        }
                
                    console.log(responceData);
        )
    }

    function formationFunction(){
        var selectDate = document.getElementById('select');
　　　　　　　//処理
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        myFetch.then(response => response.json()).then(
            clearDataElementList();
                responceData =>{...}
                    console.log(responceData);
        )
```

ここで文法エラーが出て、以降のコードが無効になっているのでしょう。

`then()`関数に指定できるパラメータは値が関数になるような「式」です。このコードでは「文 `clearDataElementList();`」と「式 `responceData => {...}`」と「文 `console.log(...);`」が書いてあって、文法エラーです。